# What is the most efficient way to filter a list of elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-filters

I have a list of images, and a data.json file which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "description" : "",
    "category": "bathroom",
    "url" : "bathroom/1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "description" : "",
    "category": "bathroom",
    "url" : "bathroom/2.jpg"
  }...
]
```

I repeat those images as such:

```
<ul ng-controller="galleryCtrl" class="gallery">
  <li ng-repeat="photo in photos" class="gallery-list-item" rel="group">
    <a href="../photos/{{photo.url}}" class="{{photo.category}} fancybox" rel="group"><img ng-src="../photos/{{photo.url}}" alt=""/>{{photo.id}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I want to add one button per "category", which will filter (ng-animate nice to have) and show only the category binded with that button.

I guess a simple way to do it would be per class, but I'm wondering if going for the photo.category value would be smarter.
I would actually prefer ideally not to add function calls in my HTML (ngClick) but I don't know if its possible to avoid.

A challenge in AngularJS is choose the best method to do an action - as there are always more than one.

Also note that I am using ui-router, so I could just use views and have one view per category.. but I think that's an overkill..

My question:

Could you list 2-3 possible solutions to the problem and only detail the best one for you?

Comment: `photo in photos | filter:photo.category` makes no sense.

Comment: Indeed, that was a leftover paste... Removed.